# How to get the data about which Android devices have certain vulnerabilities?

Tags: security

I am doing security research on Android devices.

However, I do not know which Android devices have which vulnerabilities.

For example, CVE-2013-2597 and CVE-2013-6123 work only on specific Qualcomm chipsets. If I want to buy a device for testing, I do not know which one to buy.

Is there any data available on this kind of mapping or statistics?

Comment: Are you looking for the results of vulnerability tests by device, or for hardware/software component/feature lists etc.?

Comment: Either can be good.